# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in Flink when fetching data from ValueState

Tags: java, fatal-error, apache-flink, flink-streaming

When reading data from a shared ValueState in Flink, I get an inexplicable crash in the JVM. I'm not sure if I am doing something stupid, if I have stumbled across a bug in Flink (or somewhere else), or if it is the intended behaviour (though I doubt a "fatal error in the JRE" would be intended). Can anyone shed some light on how to solve / get around this problem?

The error message I receive is:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000054e9a390, pid=6328, tid=0x00000000000002f8
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [zip.dll+0xa390]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\bjornper\eclipse_workspace\TestEnvironment\hs_err_pid6328.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I am able to reproduce the crash with the following program:

Main class:

```
package flinkjvmcrash;

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

public class MainMinimalCrash {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        //env.setParallelism(1);

        DataStream<LogRow> logRowDataStream = env.addSource(new MyDataSource());

        logRowDataStream.keyBy("sourceId").flatMap(new Aggregator());

        env.execute("My Data Flow");
    }
}
```

Aggregator:

```
package flinkjvmcrash;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichFlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeHint;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;

public class Aggregator extends RichFlatMapFunction<LogRow, LogRow> {

    // I need this class (or something similar) to process delta values between incoming LogRow objects
    public class AggregationData {
        public String release = "";
        public long timestamp = 0;
    }

    private transient ValueState<AggregationData> aggregationData;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        ValueStateDescriptor<AggregationData> descriptorAggregationData =
                new ValueStateDescriptor<AggregationData>(
                        "aggregationData",
                        TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<AggregationData>() {}),
                        new AggregationData());
        aggregationData = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptorAggregationData);
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(LogRow value, Collector<LogRow> out) throws Exception {
        AggregationData data = aggregationData.value(); // Commenting out this row makes the bug disappear

        // This function will of course do more work, but that is not relevant to the bug/crash
    }
}
```

Data source:

```
package flinkjvmcrash;

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.RichSourceFunction;

public class MyDataSource extends RichSourceFunction<LogRow> {

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<LogRow> ctx) throws Exception {
        // produces 8000 data objects in quick succession
        for (int i = 0; i < 8000; i++) {
            LogRow logRow = new LogRow();
            ctx.collect(logRow);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
    }
}
```

Data object used in the stream:

```
package flinkjvmcrash;

public class LogRow {
    public String sourceId;
    public String release;
    public Long timestamp;

    public Integer lotsOfMoreFields;
}
```

The environment I use is:

- Java 8
- Flink 1.1.3
- Eclipse IDE

System info:

```
OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 14393 (10.0.14393.0)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

Memory: 4k page, physical 8299612k(4301944k free), swap 11052124k(6589788k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_111-b14), built on Sep 22 2016 19:24:05 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
```

EDIT 1:

By changing the `AggregationData` inner class (the one used in the `ValueState`) to a `Tuple2<String, Long>` instead, the problem does not appear anymore.

EDIT 2:

It is now the day after I first posted the question, and the same code no longer reproduces the problem... The computer has been turned off during the night, but apart from that I don't know why the problem does not appear now... (even though yesterday I could reproduce the problem even after rebooting...)

On @rmetzger's request, here is the `hs_err_pid6328.log` file: https://gist.github.com/Plankton555/e6ba1224b34035e91c5d5933f1c73549

Comment: I tried to reproduce this error on my computer at it works well without any exceptions. Both with 1.1.4 and 1.1.3 . Have you tried running this exact minimal example?

Comment: Yep, I reproduced it for every "reduction step" from my original code. I guess that must mean there is something specific to my machine/configuration that at least affects the problem.

I've also just tested using a Tuple2 instead of the AggregationData object (the inner class) in the ValueState, and then it works fine.

Comment: Can you check the `C:\Users\bjornper\eclipse_workspace\TestEnvironment\hs_err_pid6328.log` and see which method call causes the failure?

Comment: I uploaded the log file at https://gist.github.com/Plankton555/e6ba1224b34035e91c5d5933f1c73549. There seem to be method calls inside Flink and Scala, from what I understand.
Also, see EDIT 2 in the question.